# Formulário de pesquisa não executa método do controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form" action="/video/pesquisa">
                        <div class="cover-pursuit-btn">
                            <button type="submit" value="Search" class="pursuit-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="coversquare">
                            <input type="text" class="square fild-placeholder" placeholder="Find in title or description" id="SearchString" name="SearchString" value="">
                        </div>

</form>
```

Meu método no controller é:

```
[Route("video/pesquisa/{SearchString}/{page?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PesquisaVideo(string SearchString, int? page)
{
...
}
```

Quando mando fazer o submit ele executa a seguinte URL:

```
http://localhost:59278/video/pesquisa?SearchString=teste
```

Não entendo porque ele não executa assim correto, uma vez que já apliquei a rota na anotação:

```
http://localhost:59278/video/pesquisa/teste
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

**ATUALIZANDO**

Esse é o RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Categoria", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

Comment: Você está com a rota `Default` configurada no `RoutesConfig.cs`?

Comment: Sim, não alterei nada no RoutesConfig.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nada. Está tudo certo. Isto porque sua `action` do `form` está configurada assim:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form" action="/video/pesquisa">
```

Atributos `GET` não se encaixam na fórmula da rota, por mais que a rota esteja correta. Isto se deve ao fato de que um atributo `GET` não é um identificador de rota, como por exemplo o clichê `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

O que acontece neste caso clichê é que o interpretador de rota analisa o endereço e considera parte da rota implicitamente como atributo. Ou seja, `id` não é considerado um parâmetro de um formulário `GET`: ele vira um parâmetro porque sua rota diz isso.

Agora, no seu caso, você está explicitamente usando um formulário e apontando para uma `action` que não conhece o valor de rota `{SearchString}`. Neste caso está sendo uma má prática porque o formulário `GET` pede variáveis livres, e você está forçando uma variável a existir, sobretudo dentro de uma rota, que não é reconhecida pelo protocolo `GET` (observe que protocolo `GET` é diferente do framework ASP.NET MVC).